# Relative layout: layout_below a CenterVertical element

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

I'm facing a problem when i want to make the button below an element that has an attribute

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

the textview is centered vertically and the button should be below it 
but that's not the case

my XML snippet looks like:

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/ecommerce1Foreground"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="ZARA WOMEN DRESS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShopNow"
            style="@style/ButtonYellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="SHOP NOW"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you If you have a fixed height. Give it to Parent i.e make your relative layout height 200dp. After that, you have to use @+id/title in your Button